# 2015 Kia forte ignition lock repair

Tags: ignition, kia, forte

I had my ignition broken during a failed theft. I have since purchased an ignition cylinder lock with new keys. If it's just a standard key that goes in the ignition and has no fob or flip out key will the new key need to be reprogrammed to the car

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! T